# Baked 2 cakes simultaneously. One sank in the middle on cooling

Tags: baking, cake

I have a gas oven. I have raised a question regarding it before, [Baking in gas oven does not brown the top](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53964/baking-in-gas-oven-does-not-brown-the-top). This time when I baked I placed a aluminum foil in bottom rack and baked 2 same size cake on the top rack. The cake on the left baked evenly and was fine. The cake on the right though browned more sank in the middle on cooling.

I had heated the oven to 180 C and baked the left cake for 30 minutes and since it got baked I removed and shifted the cake on the right in the middle as it was wobbly in the center. I baked it for 5 minutes more and then took it out. It looked fine first but when cooled it sank in the middle.
What could have gone wrong here? How can I prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason for the aluminum foil?

Comment: @user3169 The aluminum foil is placed because in my gas oven there is a issue with top not browning and bottom getting browned faster. It was suggested in [link](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53964/baking-in-gas-oven-does-not-brown-the-top)

Comment: Are the cake pans metal? And if so how thick (some low-cost baking pans using thin metal seem more likely to burn)? And does the oven maintain the correct temperature while cooking? Older or low cost ovens might have poor temp. control. I would avoid using foil to block heat. Recent ovens I have had say in the owners manual to not do this. Also it may affect the oven temperature by inaccurately affecting the thermocouple.

Comment: @user3169 then how do I fix the issue of cake not browning on top?

Comment: Can you answer my questions first?

Comment: @user3169 Sorry, the pans are metal, good-quality and thick. I do not know about the temperature maintenance while cooking as I keep the thermometer on rack during pre-heat and move it to side when I place the pans but the temperature seems to remain same.

Comment: I think you could check the temperature accuracy with any foods you bake in the oven. Try checking with something else. The temperature measured should be close to the oven indicator setting when putting food in, and stay close to that while cooking. I had an oven that when set to 350F was 425F after preheating and anywhere in between while cooking.

Comment: You can test for hot and cool spots in your oven by putting baking sheets covered in shredded coconut or slices of bread into your hot oven and seeing where it browns first/more fully. You may also want to invest in an oven thermometer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you underbaked the cake to me, the structure hadn't crystallized and therefore couldn't support the weight of the case. Non-fan ovens often have warmer and cooler spots, the cake on the left was likely in a warmer spot than the one on the right, and cooked faster. Or the cake on the left was slightly smaller and cooked faster because of it, either way when you opened the oven door all the heat went out, lengthening the time it would take to finish baking the remaining cake and you just didn't give it enough time.

Next time test the doneness of the cake using the appropriate method for that cake. I use a spring test and/or an instant read thermometer for most cakes. I don't usually use a toothpick test as I've found it to be inaccurate.

Comment: I did test it for doneness by poking a toothpick in the cake and it came out clean.

Comment: I should have called it a spring test, not a poke test, it's where you push down on the cake using your fingers and see if it springs back. If it does, the cake is done, if it doesn't it's not. I don't recommend toothpick tests, I've edited to correct this.