# How should i supposed to bake cookies in gas oven?

Tags: cookies

How should i supposed to bake cookies in gas oven? Like my gas oven burner burns from one side at a time either from bottom or top. Should i bake cookies from bottom and top equally or how should i suppose to bake it because I'm a learner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53964/baking-in-gas-oven-does-not-brown-the-top

Answer (score 1):

For baking the gas burners should be at the bottom.  You should not be able to see them.  There should be a piece of metal over them.

For broiling the gas is at the top.  You can see the flames.  Broiling is for things like meat or toasting cheese where you put them close under the flames.

Your oven should have a dial that says Bake Broil Clean and maybe other things.  Possibly it just has numbers which means degrees of Bake until you get to Broil at which point it turns on the top one.

Use the bottom burner and make cookies on middle rack.

I would be interested in seeing a photo of the dial of your oven.  You can take it with your phone and add it to the question.

Comment: Okay will show you the pic but I've a question that cookies don't need to cook from top? And why are they like being moist and not crisped if i cooked them on bottom burner?

Comment: Re bottom burner:  heat rises.  Baking involves transfer of heat via hot air.  When you are baking the higher your rack the hotter is is.  If I bake in my little oven I move the cookie sheet from bottom to top halfway thru because they are so different.

Comment: Broiler is different: it cooks via radiant heat.  The flames heat up a plate or grill and the red heat shines on the food and cooks it.  It is good for crisping but it is so hot you will not cook things thru before they burn unless they are very thin.